# Same function closure over multiple files

Tags: javascript

I have a massive function that I would like to decompose into multiple files. Here is the structure of my function:

```
var myFunction = function (argument) {
   var private1, private2, private3;

   var gadget1 = (function () {
       // Play around with private1, private2, private3, argument

       return gadget1API;
   }());

   var gadget2 = (function () {
       // Play around with private1, private2, private3, argument

       return gadget2API;
   }());

   var gadget3 = (function () {
       // Play around with private1, private2, private3, argument

       return gadget3API;
   }());

   return myFunctionAPI;
}
```

Here namespacing the gadgets to spread them over multiple files doesn't work because they all depend upon `private1, private2, private3` which are within the `myFunction` closure. For this to work, I would need the `myFunction` closure to close over 3 different files.

Comment: If you don't mind an extra step, you could use the C preprocessor (`cpp`) and `include` directives to combine your JavaScript file. It's a piece of cake together with build tools such as `ant`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create it as an object, not a closure, and load it first, something like this:

```
function myObject(argument) {
   this.arg = argument;
   this.private1 = whatever;
   this.private2 = whatever;
   this.private3 = whatever;

   this.gadget1 = (function () {
   // Play around with this.private1, this.private2, this.private3, this.arg

       return gadget1API;
   }());

   this.gadget2 = (function () {
   // Play around with this.private1, this.private2, this.private3, this.arg

       return gadget2API;
   }());

   this.gadget3 = (function () {
   // Play around with this.private1, this.private2, this.private3, this.arg

       // return gadget3API; i don't see what this is for, so commented out
   }());

   return myFunctionAPI;
}
```

And instantiate it right after you defined it

```
var myFunction = new myObject(theargument);
```

you can access it's functions like this:

```
var something1 = myFunction.gadget3();
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer is simple: It is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

It seems what you are after is a full fledged parameterized module system. Short of the inclusion of that in future versions of JavaScript/ECMAScript, perhaps it is sufficient to simulate the said closure behavior manually by parameterizing over an explicit closure environment in each individual gadget file and then tie everything back together (i.e., link the gadgets) by instantiating the gadgets.

gadget1.js:

```
var gadget1 = function (env) {
   with (env) {
   // Play around with private1, private2, private3, argument

   return gadget1API;
   }
}
```

gadget2.js:

```
var gadget2 = function (env) {
   with (env) {
   // Play around with private1, private2, private3, argument

   return gadget2API;
   }
}
```

main.js:

```
var myFunction = function (argument) {
  var private1, private2, private3;
  var gadgetFns = [gadget1, gadget2, …];
  var gadgets = [];
  function closureEnvF() { this.argument=argument, this.private1=private1, this.private2=private2, this.private3=private3 };
  var closureEnv = new closureEnvF();
  for (var i = 0; i<gadgets.length; i++) {
     gadgets[i] = gadgetFns[i].apply(null, closureEnv);
  }
  return myFunctionAPI; 
}
```

This can probably be simplified depending on whether all the elements in the closure environment are objects to begin with. It is quite a workaround, but it does illustrate the point that closures are not magic (merely a function plus an implicitly passed closure environment).